# Where has simd matrix_linear_combination been gone in iOS11?

Tags: swift, simd, ios11, swift4

```
 let m = matrix_linear_combination(alpha, v1, 1-alpha, v0)
```

matrix_linear_combination now generates "Use of unresolved identifier 'matrix_linear_combination'" error.

Any existing replacement?

PS : Should I clarify I already import simd and that there was no issue in iOS10/Swift 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short answer:*  The iOS 11/macOS 10.13 SDK renames many simd types and functions,
the prefix `matrix_` is replaced by `simd_`.

*Longer answer:*

Xcode 8 uses the iOS 10.3 (resp. macOS 10.12) SDK, and that defines
the simd matrix types as

```
typedef struct { vector_float2 columns[2]; } matrix_float2x2;
```

and the functions

```
static matrix_float2x2 __SIMD_ATTRIBUTES__ matrix_linear_combination(float __a, matrix_float2x2 __x, float __b, matrix_float2x2 __y);
```

These are imported into Swift 3 as

```
public struct matrix_float2x2 { ... }
// ...
```

and

```
public func matrix_linear_combination(_ __a: Float, _ __x: matrix_float2x2, _ __b: Float, _ __y: matrix_float2x2) -> matrix_float2x2
// ...
```

Xcode 9 uses the iOS 11 (resp. macOS 10.13) SDK and that defines the
types as

```
typedef struct { simd_float2 columns[2]; } simd_float2x2;
// ...
```

and the functions

```
static simd_float2x2 SIMD_CFUNC simd_linear_combination(float __a, simd_float2x2 __x, float __b, simd_float2x2 __y);
// ...
```

These are imported into Swift 4 as

```
public struct simd_float2x2 { ... }
// ...
```

and

```
public func simd_linear_combination(_ __a: Float, _ __x: simd_float2x2, _ __b: Float, _ __y: simd_float2x2) -> simd_float2x2
// ...
```

Comment: Alas, I already import simd (importing simd.matrix doesn't bring any value).

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca: They were just renamed between Swift 3 and 4. It has nothing to do with the iOS version. I mentioned `simd.matrix` only because that's where you find the definitions.

Comment: yep, but replacing import simd by simd.matrix does nothing more. I still have the issue. I'm puzzle… Im compiling against Xcode 9 beta 2 (Version 9.0 beta / 9M136h) targeting iOS 11.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca: Perhaps I expressed myself badly. You must still `import simd`. Then `simd_linear_combination(...)` should be available, it worked for me.

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca: Did you replace **matrix**_linear_combination by **simd**_linear_combination? It works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148626/discussion-between-stephane-de-luca-and-martin-r).

Comment: Note also that the SIMD Swift matrix types and the C SIMD matrix types are now the same. So while you still need functions like `simd_linear_combination` for the more esoteric operations, you don't need to use functions like `simd_mul` for matrix-matrix and matrix/vector multiplication anymore — you can just use the `*` operator instead.